# How to alias git checkout -b with a string format for the branch name

Tags: bash, git, git-config, git-alias

My team uses a format for our branch names for uniformity.  For a given branch, the format would be: "feature/TeamName-CardNumber".  The card number is the only part of this that will change, so I would like to make an alias such as:

```
git cobf '111'
```

Where 111 is the card number.

I tried this command to set the alias:

```
git config --global alias.cobf 'checkout -b feature/TeamName-"
```

But when running the `git cobf 111` command, I get an error saying that 111 is not a commit and a branch cannot be created from it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Why does it fail?**

It's because after expansion of the alias, your command is resolved as

```
git checkout -b feature/TeamName- 111
```

...which to git means "checkout a new branch named `feature/TeamName-` pointing at *committish* `111`" (roughly put, "committish" is something that is either a commit or something pointing at one, like a branch or tag)

---

**What to do instead?**

To avoid that, use an ad-hoc bash function to handle parameters more conveniently :

```
git config --global alias.cobf '!f() { git checkout -b feature/TeamName-$1; }; f'
```

Note : the quotes are unneeded when you'll call the alias, `git cobf 111` will do.